# Uncaught Firebase: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)

Tags: firebase

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW9fe.png)There is no error when the code is being run using Firebase configuration directly. when I am putting firebase configuration key in the environment variable ,then it throw an error "Firebase:Error(auth/invalid-api-key)"

Answer (score 0):

after adding environment variable you have to restart the live server.